# blank screen, ubuntu

Tags: lenovo

I had a blank screen on my laptop (lenovo ideapad S415touch)and i checked couple solutions on the forums while using my external monitor and I found this one:

"It worked for my Ubuntu 14, Lenovo B570, Intel Graphics.

Open a terminal and create the following configuration file, if it does not exist:

sudo touch /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf

Now we need to edit this file. You can use any editor be it a terminal one or graphical.

sudo gedit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf

Add the following lines to this file:

Section "Device"
        Identifier  "card0"
        Driver      "intel"
        Option      "Backlight"  "intel_backlight"
        BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"

EndSection

Save it. Log out and log in back."

I did it and since then, I can't even use the external monitor, both are blank. How can I reinstall ubuntu at least ?

Answer (score 0):

Did it exist? You can choose a setting on bootup which lets you boot into save mode or terminal mode or just text mode and stuff...

if it didn't exist just type sudo rm -r /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf

(not sure about the -r option, but guess without)

if it did, type sudo nano /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf and edit the file to its root.

exit and reboot or use a live dvd to edit your system.